# How to use @onchange in mvc dropdown

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Please help me How can i use @onchange in mvc dropdownList

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.SaveHybridEmp.Cnt_Id, new SelectList(Model.GetCount, "Cnt_Id", "Cnt_Name"), "Selected Country", 
  new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "hell(this.Cnt_Id);" })
</div>
```

**Angularcode**

```
app.controller('MyCntrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.hell = function () {
  alert('change..');
}
```

Comment: MVC just generates the HTML to output to the page. Can you [edit] your question and paste in the generated HTML (from view source or developer tools)? But based purely on what you have posted, there does not appear to be anything specifically wrong with how you have set the `onchange` up. I suspect it is an angular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh hell = no!
That won't work. The onchange handler specified in the razor helper will bind to a javascript method specified in local scope. The angular scope is separated. 
You need to define a model for the select html control and use the ng-change directive.

[Ng-Change Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

[Html Select](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

P.S.> for clean code rule, you might want to mix as little as posible razor helpers with angular directives

Note: I've assumed you use angular 1